# I am not getting to click on href link

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to click on `Href` link but with no success.

This is the HTML of the page I am trying to click:

[image]

And here is the code that I tryed to use.

```
Welcome Page Should Be Open
Location Should Be    ${WELCOME URL}
Title Should Be    OrangeHRM
Click Link   id=welcome
Wait Until Element Is Visible   id=welcome-menu   8
#Click Link href=https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/auth/logout
Click Link xpath://a{test()='logout'}
```

I tried with "href" and "xpath", but both give the error:

> No keyword with name XXXXXX found.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with this code
xpath://a[@href='/index.php/auth/logout']

Comment: What is the actual keyword that is not found? If it's this `Click Link xpath://a{test()='logout'}`, then check that it has at least two spaces after `Link` and before xpath. Also change `{}` in xpath to `[]`.

Comment: many Thank you @RushabhRakholiya it worked.

Comment: @Eduardo
You're welcome
Please mark as upvote
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you only have a single space between `Click Link` and the xpath. You need two or more spaces to separate a keyword from its arguments.

Also, `xpath://a{test()='logout'}` is not a valid xpath expression. You need to change the curly braces to square brackets, and change `test` to `text`. You also need to change `logout` to `Logout`.

```
xpath://a[text()='Logout']
```

For [Click Link](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link), you can also just specify the link text or href, for example:

```
Click Link  Logout
```